# Im having trouble figuring out this part var z=x+y; document.write(x + "<br>");

Tags: javascript, variables, math

```
<script>
    var x=5; var y=6; var z=x+y;  
    document.write(x + "<br>"); 
    document.write(y + "<br>"); 
    document.write(z + "<br>"); 
</script>
```

I understand that the plus signs are needed to add the var 5 & 6 and out put to z
but why does z have a plus sign?

Answer (score 1):

`+` is also used to concatenate two strings in JavaScript, which means joining two strings. Your last statement is concatenating the value of `z` with `<br>`, which results in `11<br>` in your case. This is then being written by `document.write`.

However, the operation of the `+` operator fully depends on the context. Consider this -

```
document.write (3 + 5 + " hello");
```

The above will write the `8 hello` string on the page. This is due to the reason that expression are evaluated from left to right, so `3 + 5` is first evaluated to `8`, which is then concatenated with the string to produce the string `8 hello`. So the first `+` operator is acting like an arithmetic operator, while the second one is acting like a concatenation operator. But if you write -

```
document.write(3 + " hello");
```

then the `+` operator will act here like a concatenation operator, and will concatenate those two values.

Fore more information, you can visit the following pages -

1. [Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)
2. [String Operators in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators)

Comment: @user3282504: No if you want to display x,y,z separated with commas you should write it like this,

`document.write(x+","+y+","+z);`

Comment: @user3282504 Which plus sign are you referring to? The one on the first line, or the one on the fourth line?

Comment: fourth line..  im not seeing why z needs a plus sign?

Comment: z= x+y so why add it?

Comment: @user3282504: the fourth line isn't performing any arithmetic addition, it's performing a string join operation. There is a lot of differences between these two.

Comment: The fourth line is doing the same thing as the second and third lines, except with `z` instead of `x` or `y`. This is extremely basic stuff. I suggest yhat you go through some JavaScript lessons or tutorials to get up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are concatinating with a `STRING`

Answer (score 0):

`+` will concatenate based on type of operands.

```
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 + ' bread' = '3 bread'
1 + ' bread' = '1 bread'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fizerkhan/R3nLf/

Comment: thanks guys as you can tell im new at this.. Im using w3schools, but it doesnt answer all of my questions..

Comment: @user3282504: Ditch w3schools (it's bad) and use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide), http://eloquentjavascript.net/ and/or http://www.quirksmode.org/js/contents.html. There are so many better tutorials out there than w3schools.

Comment: @user3282504 if you use Chrome, open the dev tools > console(ctrl + shift + j) and play with javascript there. If you're using Firefox, install Firebug. :)

Comment: You can either use chrome developer console or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). I prefer [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) since you can play with `HTML` and `CSS` also

Comment: wow and thanks again..do you guys know of any  good free video tutorials?

Comment: For web, you can try http://www.codecademy.com/, https://www.udacity.com/courses#!/All, https://www.codeschool.com/, https://teamtreehouse.com

Comment: thanks.. is it suggested that I read all of the documents in the java-script guides? lot of material...

Comment: For learning javascript(any language), learn simple things and practice consistently.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, `+` is used to add numbers, numbers and strings, strings and numbers, strings and strings. It wouldn't make sense to create another operator just for strings so they 'overloaded' the + operator to work on strings too.

Also, `+` operator can work as a converter to number.
Example:

```
var x = +"123";
```

Here, x will be a number, not a string, because + is doing the conversion.

```
typeof x; // "number"
```

Use it carrefully, you must remember that if the first operand is a string, the result will be computed as a string.

```
var x = "5" + 67; // x = "567" not 72!
```